# MySQL - Stored procedure with multiple result sets

Tags: mysql

Am using two select statements in a stored procedure but it is returning only single select statement  table,how to get the both tables record set please suggest me?

Comment: Post the stored procedure and describe in detail what you expect it to do.

Comment: how are you doing it, post your code also please.

Comment: What's you client environment?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) extension in php to be able to get multiple result resources from stored procedures - the standard PHP mysql interface doesn't support it.

From a now offline introduction, this seems like a pretty good introduction to the class, especially:

> First thing’s first, you shouldn’t
>   treat calls to stored procedures which
>   return a resultset as you would normal
>   SQL queries. The reason being is that
>   when executed, a stored procedure will
>   give you two resultsets back. One with
>   the actual resultset and another which
>   sends the status of the stored
>   procedure (OK/ERR).

Comment: +1 , add example link :
http://www.devcomments.com/Interesting-MySQLi-issue-Stored-Procedures-with-Multiple-Results-to160455.htm

Comment: Added a link, and a quote from the post.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) is an example on how it is done in c.

EDIT:
[Here](http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2007/06/01/mysql-multiple-result-procs-in-php/) is an example on how it is done in php

Answer (score 0):

union keyword? It is hard to answer without query.