# laravel fetching multiple resultset

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have been trying to fetch data using stored procedure in laravel.But I am only getting the first result set.

```
$data=DB::select("call get_detail('".$id."')");
```

I have also tried the below link(can be used to better understanding of what i am asking) [how to fetch multiple result set from a mysql stored procedure in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695287/how-to-fetch-multiple-result-set-from-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-laravel/28043584#28043584).
But getting the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053
```

Here is My sample stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`()
 BEGIN 
 SELECT * FROM user_master;
 SELECT * from group_master; 
END
```

Comment: Could you paste the procedure definition as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394947/mysql-stored-procedure-with-multiple-result-sets

Comment: just added a SP. take a look @ka_lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@manish-dixit

I had a same problem and below answer is perfect to me.

[how to fetch multiple result set from a mysql stored procedure in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695287/how-to-fetch-multiple-result-set-from-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-laravel)

And I recommend to fill in 'DB::select' like below

`$data=DB::select("call get_detail(?)", array($id);`

I hope this answer help you after 5 months. :)

Comment: thanks. Tried your link its working fine.I guess i missed something last time.